# How to understand tf.get_collection() in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

I am confused by `tf.get_collection()` form the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/framework.html#Graph.get_collection), it says that

> Returns a list of values in the collection with the given name.

And an example from the Internet is here

```
from_vars = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, from_scope)
```

Is it means that it collects variables from `tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES`  to `from_scope`?

However, how can I use this function if I want to get variables from another scope? Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A collection is nothing but a named set of values.

Every value is a node of the computational graph.

Every node has its name and the name is composed by the concatenation of scopes, `/` and values, like: `preceding/scopes/in/that/way/value`

`get_collection`, without `scope` allow fetching every value in the collection without applying any filter operation.

When the `scope` parameter is present, every element of the collection is filtered and its returned only if the name of the node starts with the specified `scope`.

Comment: I am so confused on how to use this api. I am using it for Optimize functions and it's returning "No variables to optimize". I am pretty sure my scope is wrong. But how do I know the scope of my variable.  To specify scope I used tf.name_scope('CNN/Encoder') and to fetch I used 'CNN'. Please help me where I may be going wrong

Comment: `tf.name_scope` is different from `tf.variable_scope`! name scope changes the scope of your operations only, not of the variables. You were looking for `tf.variable_scope`. I suggest you read this article https://pgaleone.eu/tensorflow/go/2017/05/29/understanding-tensorflow-using-go/ in ordert to understand how variables (and tf in general) work under the hood

Comment: note that it equal to find variable names **start with** the scope.

Answer (score 1):

As described in the string doc:

> - `TRAINABLE_VARIABLES`: the subset of `Variable` objects that will
>     be trained by an optimizer.

and

> scope: (Optional.) A string. If supplied, the resulting list is filtered
>           to include only items whose `name` attribute matches `scope` using
>           `re.match`. Items without a `name` attribute are never returned if a
>           scope is supplied. The choice of `re.match` means that a `scope` without
>           special tokens filters by prefix.

So it will return the list of trainable variables in the given scope.